# Navigator.userAgent.match - specific handset identification

Tags: javascript, php, html, navigator

I'm recognising when a user is using certain phones using navigator.userAgent.match but with Android there are many tablets/phones/set-top boxes. So I've got

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)){
```

But how would I specifically then select a HTC One S from the list of Androids? It's user agent is:

```
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; HTC_One_S Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

I can say Android 4.0 but then there are a lot of products with Android 4.0. Next step would be to check the screen size, which I can do, but is there a way to specifically just check if the navigator.userAgent matches EXACTLY a HTC One S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `if(navigator.userAgent.match(/HTC_One_S/i)){` ?

Comment: correct. Solved it already, forgot to close this. Thanks anyway. For anyone that sees this, this will work!